# How do I correct zfs pool trying to use incorrect device after reboot?

Tags: zfs

I recently rebooted a server and after boot one of my zfspools was unavailable.

> pool: stor4  state: UNAVAIL status: One or more devices could not be
>   used because the label is missing
>           or invalid.  There are insufficient replicas for the pool to continue
>           functioning. action: Destroy and re-create the pool from
>           a backup source.    see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-5E   scan: none requested config:
>
> ```
>     NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
>     stor4       UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
>       raidz2-0  UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
>         sdaa    ONLINE       0     0     0
>         sdac    ONLINE       0     0     0
>         sdad    ONLINE       0     0     0
>         sdag    ONLINE       0     0     0
>         sdai    ONLINE       0     0     0
>         sdak    ONLINE       0     0     0
>         sdam    ONLINE       0     0     0
>         sdao    UNAVAIL      0     0     0  corrupted data
>         sdap    UNAVAIL      0     0     0
>         sdaq    UNAVAIL      0     0     0
>         sdar    UNAVAIL      0     0     0
>         sdas    UNAVAIL      0     0     0
>         sdat    UNAVAIL      0     0     0
>         sdau    UNAVAIL      0     0     0
>         sdav    UNAVAIL      0     0     0
> ```

It seemed odd to me that suddenly all of the drives would go bad. Upon further investigation I found that /dev/sdao is not part of the array, rather part of an lvm.

> UUID="dff51eba-e2ce-4b11-8fe5-7cc8d4d28d5b" TYPE="ext2" /dev/sdao5:
>   UUID="V9Y5aB-DbB2-Djly-ndTD-nwbb-ADi2-iBOHte" TYPE="LVM2_member"

So it appears that the pools is trying to grab /dev/sdao which isn't part of the pool and then dies.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this issue. Apparently lvm and zfs don't play nicely together.

1. Power down jbod enclosure
2. reboot machine
3. zpool status nolonger shows the drive.
4. zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-id stor4

   pool: stor4
   state: ONLINE
    scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0h2m with 0 errors on Wed Apr  6 13:15:36 2016
   config:

   ```
       NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
       stor4                                           ONLINE       0     0     0
         raidz2-0                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
           ata-WDC_WD4000FYYZ-01UL1B2_WD-WCC134LLA13H  ONLINE       0     0     0
           ata-WDC_WD4000FYYZ-01UL1B2_WD-WCC130YUZ78J  ONLINE       0     0     0
           ata-WDC_WD4000FYYZ-01UL1B2_WD-WCC130ADRPT2  ONLINE       0     0     0
           ata-WDC_WD4000FYYZ-01UL1B2_WD-WCC133YHCH74  ONLINE       0     0     0
           ata-WDC_WD4000FYYZ-01UL1B2_WD-WCC134HF0CN1  ONLINE       0     0     0
           ata-WDC_WD4000FYYZ-01UL1B2_WD-WCC133CL339U  ONLINE       0     0     0
           ata-WDC_WD4000FYYZ-01UL1B2_WD-WCC133YHC7A8  ONLINE       0     0     0
           ata-WDC_WD4000FYYZ-01UL1B2_WD-WCC134PDTNA9  ONLINE       0     0     0
           ata-WDC_WD4000FYYZ-01UL1B2_WD-WCC134HF0TF5  ONLINE       0     0     0
           ata-WDC_WD4000FYYZ-01UL1B2_WD-WCC134HF01HR  ONLINE       0     0     0
           ata-WDC_WD4000FYYZ-01UL1B2_WD-WCC132RDTE7E  ONLINE       0     0     0
           ata-WDC_WD4000FYYZ-01UL1B2_WD-WCC134PDT71R  ONLINE       0     0     0
           ata-WDC_WD4000FYYZ-01UL1B2_WD-WCC136HXYZS3  ONLINE       0     0     0
           ata-WDC_WD4000FYYZ-01UL1B2_WD-WCC136PT6DE9  ONLINE       0     0     0
           ata-WDC_WD4000FYYZ-01UL1B2_WD-WCC133FE5JND  ONLINE       0     0     0
       spares
         ata-WDC_WD4000FYYZ-01UL1B2_WD-WCC131FYE89J    AVAIL
   ```

The array is online and data is intact. It seems as though lvm which is managing /root was stepping on zfs and assinging one of zfs's drive letters to its physical volume. I should note that zpool export would error because status was unavail. Using the id should keep this type of thing from happening in the future.

I hope this helps anyone who runs into the same issue.